# my result is not right , can't find the error? (may be wrong about compare)

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address

```
int l_search (char* list, int count, char* token);
```

`list` – the starting address of the list of structures to be searched

`count` – total number of names in the list

`token` – name to be search in the list

```
enter code here

struct student
{
  int   ID;
   char name[20];
};

int l_search (char* list, int count, char* token)
{
__asm
{
     struct student
{
     int    ID;
     char   name[20];
};


   mov eax, 0; zero out the result
     mov esi, list; move the list pointer to ESI
    ; fill in your code here

    mov edi, token; move the token name pointer to edi
    mov ebx, 0; index of each construct in array
    mov edx, esi; set a pointer for each inside construct 
    add edx, 4; point to the first character in the string
compare:
    mov ecx, byte ptr[edx]; store the character to compare 
    cmp ecx, byte ptr[edi]; compare relative character 
    jne checkCase ;
nextletter:
    add edx, 1; to next character  
    add edi, 1;  to next charcter 
    cmp byte ptr[edi], 0; check the end of string 
    je found;
    jmp compare; continue compare 
checkCase:
     xor ecx, 24h; invert case 
     cmp ecx, byte ptr[edi] ; recompare the character with case insensitive
     jne nextConstruct; to next construct in the array 
     jmp nextletter; continue check next character 
nextConstruct: 
     add esi, 24; point to next construct 
     mov edx, esi; set the inside construct's character pointer 
     add edx, 4; point to first character 
     add ebx,1; to the next element in the array 
     cmp ebx, count; check arrays' boundary 
     jge finish;
     jmp compare ; continue compare 
found:
     mov eax, ebx; get the indext of the found name 
     add eax, 1;  get the ID 
    jmp nextConstruct;  continue checking next construct 

finish:


 }

}
```

Comment: What result are you expecting? What result did you get? Please explain.

Comment: How can something like this `mov ecx, byte ptr[edx]` even assemble?

Comment: cmp ecx, byte ptr [edi]???? 32 bits compared with an 8 bit??

Comment: `xor ecx, 24h; invert case` -> in what encoding? (`xor cl,20h` would made sense in ASCII). You can shorten the `nextConstruct:` code: reuse two more instructions from ahead of `compare:`. The `found` code doesn't make sense to me. Why +1? In C/ASM indexes into array start from 0. Or if ID was to be returned, then `mov eax,[esi]` is needed. And then any way, it continues with nextConstruct, instead of returning the value. Weird.

Comment: Please tag assembly questions with the architecture as well.

Comment: It's good that you commented your code.  It would be even better if you indented the comments to a consistent column, so the eye can see where the instruction ends while quickly reading through.  See [this asm style guide](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/assembly-style.html), and other links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).